# Did Michael Corleone ever get revenge against those who killed his wife?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather, the-godfather-2, the-godfather-3

Did Michael Corleone ever get revenge against those who killed his wife?

I just watched the 3 *Godfather* movies again and I was not able to figure out who made the attempt on his life and in the process killing his wife with the car bomb Sicily in the first movie. I know it was one of his body guards that planted the bomb, but I could not get who was actually behind it. I am guessing it was probably the Barzini crime family for the killing of Virgil Sollozzo, but I am just making an assumption there and if in fact it was the Barzini crime family then obviously he did get his revenge. I was hoping someone could back this assumption up, or not.

### So did Michael Corleone ever get revenge against those who killed his wife?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So did Michael Corleone ever get revenge against those who killed his wife?

## Yes.

There is a deleted scene in *The Godfather Part II* where Fabrizzio is found...and his involvement with the Barzini family.

https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x35geuo

...and then another where he is killed.

The Barzini's were, of course, disposed of in that long murder/revenge/power grab sequence in *The Godfather*.

The source novel makes this clearer.

> Don Corleone nodded. “Revenge is a dish that tastes best when it is cold,” he said. “I would not have made that peace but that I knew you would never come home alive otherwise. **I’m surprised, though, that Barzini still made a last try at you.** Maybe it was arranged before the peace talk and he couldn’t stop it. Are you sure they were not after Don Tommasino?”
>
> Michael said, “That’s the way it was supposed to look. And it would have been perfect, even you would never have suspected. Except that I came out alive. I saw Fabrizzio going through the gate, running away. And of course I’ve checked it all out since I’ve been back.”
>
> “Have they found that shepherd?” the Don asked.
>
> “I found him,” Michael said. **“I found him a year ago.** He’s got his own little pizza place up in Buffalo. New name, phony passport and identification. He’s doing very well is Fabrizzio the shepherd.”

...

> The gunman said, “Fabrizzio, Michael Corleone sends you his regards.” He extended the gun so that it was only a few inches from the counterman’s skull and pulled the trigger.
>
> Mario Puzo - *The Godfather*

Comment: Interesting.  Do you know where those clips are from?  One of the DVD/Blu-Ray releases, I'm assuming.

Comment: That would be my guess. I have the box set but haven't reviewed them. I was lucky enough to find these on YouTube

Comment: "He’s doing very well is Fabrizzio the shepherd.” Is there a typo ther?

Comment: Nope, direct copy from the book. It's an older way of saying that he has done well for himself... But it is proper English.

Comment: 'He is, is he.'